# JobScheduler doesn't run in MVC project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, quartz.net, job-scheduling

I'm running a MVC5 Project and I use a JobScheduler to read with an defined interval files from a specified directory and parse them for getting some information. In my local development environment everything's working fine but on the test environment the job doesn't run. I noticed that because I wrote a simple debug-function which shall write runtime variables into a text file. But this text file just didn't get any input at all.

On the test environment I'm running an IIS7.5.

Do I need any further configurations to get a job I'm using in my dev environment running on an IIS?

If you need any further information, I'll hand them in but yet I've no clue where the problem could be so I can't you more input now.

Comment: What is job sheduler? This one?  https://kb.sos-berlin.com/display/PKB/JobScheduler

Comment: Try quartz or hangfire. I use hangfire in production, everything works fine.

Comment: Windows JobScheduler or Quartz?

Answer (score 1):

Usinq Quartz in a web application will eventually cause you problem. A web application, after some inactivity time, will fall in some kind of 'sleep mode'. When this happen, your jobs scheduled in quartz will never get fire. I would suggest to make a separated windows service to run your jobs.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I thought about using Hangfire, but first I want to add: The jobs should have been run once after I started the web application. Shouldn't they run at least in that moment? Or how can I understand that sleep mode?

Comment: @Zumarta your right, the job should be running as in your local environment, I was just mentioning the problem on a long term base. To trace your problem, I would suggest to use JobListeners and add logging to trace where your problem is http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorial/trigger-and-job-listeners.html

Comment: I couldn't solve that problem and wrote an console application that will be executed through Windows Task Scheduler. A way more complicated but at least it should work.